# Duplicate in Excel

Tags: excel

I am having an issue with excel formula which I am unable to write. I have 2 columns Interest rate and Maturity. Through pivot I get the data year wise. Problem is that when there are multiple values for same year, pivot should keep value as blank and I also need to add a formula that checks if interest rate for particular year remains same like in below case of 2021. If that stands true then I need to populate value. If you provide me a code for VBA or formula then it will be a big help !!!

```
Int Rate    Maturity
2.14%   2020
4.08%   2023
3.82%   2024
3.19%   2026
3.93%   2027
2.11%   2021
2.11%   2021
2.79%   2019
2.99%   2023
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

1. Start with a simple `COUNTIF` to count whether a year is duplicate or not.
2. Then create a (hidden) column that concatenates the year and its interest rate by using `CONCAT`.
3. Now perform the same `COUNTIF` on the column containing the concatenated data. By testing this column, you are testing the uniqueness of a combination "year-interest rate".
4. Use a simple `IF`. If the number you obtained in (1) is equal to the number obtained in (3) it means the year/interest rate combination is valid. If the numbers are not equal, it means there are at least 2 conflicting entries.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joris. This is helpful but in step 4, I am unable to retrieve the value for interest rate by using IF formula. I have also applied IF(match(and formula to check but its not working. Problem is in deriving the value if true where there needs to be a reference mentioned but in IF formula there is no way to reference it.

Comment: I've applied another logic but it is also not working:=IF(L5=M5,VLOOKUP(O5,$G$5:$H$1300,2,FALSE),"")

Comment: I added a screenshot that mimics the step by step explanation. In the column "rate or blank" you should see that it does as expected. It either gives the interest rate for that year, or if there are multiple rates it returns blank.

Comment: Ahh. I was using values in pivot with decending in order. So I had only 1 row for 2021 and starting with 2019. Could you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: Hi Joris, Could you please take a look and share your thought if I can pull data with an alternate formula. I need to match the year with year and retrieve the interest rate only if interest rates either match for particular year and irrespective of times the value is. If interest rate is there for multiple times and not matching then it should leave it blank. Also to note that I would have more data of interest rate and year and when I make pivot then year would show once only.

Comment: Hi @Sharmil, can you please share what you've tried?

Comment: I've applied logic but it is also not working:=IF(L5=M5,VLOOKUP(O5,$G$5:$H$1300,2,FALSE),""). Can it be possible with Index and Match formula? I am not so good with Index and Match formula.

Comment: Hello Joris, any thought?